# Averaging 3 integers

Tags: c

My assignment is to fix the code.  I have my edited code below and the original code below that.  I figure I still have a few errors in here.  My error checking doesnt seem to work, and I am not sure if my getchar() function is written or working properly.

Please assume I know nothing becasue that is fairly accurate.

The code compiles, but the answer is always 2. I am about 4 hours into this piece of code with 3 more to work after this.

#### My code

```
#include <stdio.h> 

double get_number(double num);

main () {
  double n1,n2,n3;
  double average;

  printf("\nCompute the average of 3 integers\n");
  printf("--------------------------------\n");
  n1 = get_number(1);
  n2 = get_number(2);
  n3 = get_number(3);
  average = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3;
  printf("The average is %0.2f\n",average);
}

double get_number(double num) { 
  double value = 0;
  char c;
  int i;
  printf("Please input number %d: ", num);

  while (c = getchar != '\n') { 
    if ( (c>9) || (c<0) ) { 
      printf("Incorrect character entered as a number - %c\n",c);
      return(0);
    }
    else {
    value = num;
    }
  }
  return(value);
}
```

#### Original code

```
#include <stdio.h> 

main () {
  double n1,n2,n3;
  double average;

  printf("\nCompute the average of 3 integers\n");
  printf("--------------------------------\n");
  n1 = get_number(1);
  n2 = get_number(2);
  n3 = get_number(3);
  average = (n1 + n2 + n3)/3;
  printf("The average is %0.2f\n",average);
}

double get_number(int num) { 
  double value = 0;
  char c;
  printf("Please input number %d: ", num);
  while (c = getchar() != '\n') { 
    if ( (c<=9) && (c>=0) ) { 
      printf("Incorrect character entered as a number - %c\n",c);
      exit(-1);
    }
    else {
      value = 10*value + c - '0';
    }
  }
  return(value);
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a debugger that supports line-by-line step through debugging? This is a good way to find bugs in code.

Comment: I have been given an insight debugger, but do not know how to use it yet.

Comment: I am surprised the corrected code compiles because `getchar` should be `getchar()`.

Comment: Looks like you're having trouble with at least two things. Remember that a character is a 1 byte integer value and that the character `'1'` does *not* have the value `1`. Look up ASCII at this point. Then determine how your `get_number` deals with an input value of "10" and how will the original code deal with it. Do you see the difference and understand what the original did?

Comment: You return from the get_number function what you pass in: `double get_number(double num)` ... `value=num;` ... `return value;` and `(1 +  2 + 3) / 3` is 2

Comment: thanks Matthew, I changed that, but it did not seem to fix the output or error checking

Comment: ok thank you, I will look up the ascii values and the other thing

Comment: I do not fully understand what the original did

Comment: You can download a free C/C++ environment with a proper debugger. (Visual Studio Express works, but there are probably others).

Comment: If you don't have time to use learn the debugger, then sprinkle printf's throughout your code to show you what portions of your code are executing and what are the values of your local variables.  Add and remove printf's as needed as you narrow down problems.  For example, add printf's to show  the `value` variable before and after the line `value = 10*value + c - '0';`.The key to debugging is visually how the code is supposed to work and figuring out where real execution deviates from expected behavior.

Comment: You'd have a much easier time using the debugger. It's an up-front investment in time, but you will save yourself hours or time later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

1. You should be using '9' and '0', since you want the ASCII values for digit '9' (0x39) and '0' (0x30), not 0x9 and 0x0.

```
if ( (c>'9') || (c<'0') ) {
```

2. != has higher precedence than =, so you need parens.  Learn [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), and if you're in doubt, use parens:

3. `getchar` is a function not a variable.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
```

4.   You use the wrong conversion.  `num` is a double, so you would need `%f`.  Or, you could make `num` a `int`.

```
printf("Please input number %f: ", num);
```

5. You never actually use c in any way (except error checking).  You always return 0 or `num` (see your else clause), which makes no sense.  The else body of the original is correct.

Comment: To make this more explicit, Matthew means use `'0'` (value of ASCII character '0') instead of the number `0`.

Comment: The code with `(c = getchar != '\n')` compiles because that spelling of `getchar` is not an invocation of the `getchar()` macro in the `<stdio.h>` header (because it isn't followed by an open parenthesis), so it must be the name of the function that is also required, and the expression as a whole is checking whether the pointer to function is equal to a newline (it isn't!), and assigning the boolean value of the comparison to `c`. The compiler should be having fits about it if warnings are enabled - but it 'compiles'.

Answer (score 1):

You got the floating point parsing all wrong and shouldn't be doing it yourself. There's an easier way:

```
double get_number(double num) { 
  double value = 0.0;
  printf("Please input number %lf: ", num);
  scanf("%lf", &value);
  return(value);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is an exercise and that the original code eats one char at a time. He may be expected to do it by hand...

Comment: ok, thank everyone for their help, I am going to work on all of these things and more importantly try to understand them, and then repost my reedited if I have more problems

Answer (score 1):

The issues with the **original** program are:

1. getchar() returns an ASCII code, and the condition was wrong. When checking for boundaries, use `((c<'0') || (c>'9'))`.
2. For the `exit` function you need to include "stdlib.h".
3. For the `main` function to understand what is `get_number`, you need to either move the function to be before the `main` function, or you can use a forward declaration.
4. The assignment operator (`=`) has lower precedence than the inequality operator (`!=`), so you need to use parenthesis, like: `((c = getchar()) != '\n')`

You have actually created several more issues, so I wouldn't rely on your code.

In any case, in general - it is advised you study how to use a debugger. Once your code is compiling (and for that you'll need to get accustomed to the compilation error messages), you need to start debugging your code. I suggest you take some time to learn how to set breakpoints, set watches, and go step by step into your code. That skill is absolutely essential for a good developer.

Comment: thank you for breaking it down for me.  I wondered if I had installed the wrong version of something and thats why I could not use the exit function.  and Ok I will take your advice and learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about correcting the code ...

1. http://ideone.com/a0UMm -- compilation errors
2. http://ideone.com/ljUg1 -- warnings, but it works now
3. http://ideone.com/Qd0gp -- no errors, no warnings, test run ok

For 1. I used the "original code" as posted by you.

For 2. I used `int main(void)`, declared the function `get_number` before defining `main`, added parenthesis in line 20, and added `#include <stdlib.h>`

For 3. I added `return 0;` before the final `}` of `main`. I also removed the extra output that messed up the ideone interface (it looks better on an interactive interface)

---

**Edit** more tests needed to complete the task of correcting the original code

Comment: Note that reading characters with getchar() should include a test for EOF - but that requires you to define `c` as an `int` and not as a `char`.  However, the code will not behave well if there is less input than three numbers each on one line.  (Applies to original as well as your final version.)